# dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifacts

I am getting below error when i am doing build project ..
in jenkins i have given git url to fetch the code ..and its getting the code but after few steps execution in  jenkins console its showing below error

```
   Parsing POMs
    [ushell-selenium-tests] $ /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java -cp /root/.jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven31-agent-1.5.jar:/usr/maven/apache-maven-3.3.3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/usr/maven/apache-maven-3.3.3/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main /usr/maven/apache-maven-3.3.3 /usr/apache/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/jenkins/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.52.jar /root/.jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven31-interceptor-1.5.jar /root/.jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.5.jar 46554
    <===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
    Executing Maven:  -B -f /root/.jenkins/jobs/Project 32 test ushell 1 fb_search_app selenium/workspace/ushell-selenium-tests/pom.xml install
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [WARNING] 
    [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.sap.ushell:ushell-selenium-tests:jar:1.33.0-SNAPSHOT
    [WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.scope' for org.testng:testng:jar must be one of [provided, compile, runtime, test, system] but is 'integration-test'. @ line 63, column 10
    [WARNING] 
    [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
    [WARNING] 
    [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
    [WARNING] 
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building ushell-selenium-tests 1.33.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 1.988 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-01T16:24:45+02:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 15M/608M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Name or service not known: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org: Name or service not known -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
    [JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/jobs/Project 32 test ushell 1 fb_search_app selenium/workspace/ushell-selenium-tests/pom.xml to com.sap.ushell/ushell-selenium-tests/1.33.0-SNAPSHOT/ushell-selenium-tests-1.33.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
    /root/.jenkins/jobs/Project 32 test ushell 1 fb_search_app selenium/workspace/ushell-selenium-tests/pom.xml is not inside /root/.jenkins/jobs/Project 32 test ushell 1 fb_search_app selenium/workspace/root/.jenkins/jobs/Project 32 test ushell 1 fb_search_app selenium/workspace/ushell-selenium-tests/; will archive in a separate pass
    channel stopped
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Your log output needs to be formatted better if you want people to be able to read it

Comment: Did you try to add maven home in jenkins config, and pass setting.xml, And if you r using proxy, config your setting.xml for proxy. I have same issue resolve by above.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the "Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org: Name or service not known" error by using another internet connection. The first one had a proxy in place which did not allow to download anything from the repo.